# Better way for hidden a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm trying to close a div settings his opacity to 0. But it doesn't work

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div id='divinfo'  style='position:absolute; bottom:2px; right:8px; width:40px; height: 41px; '><img id='divinfo' ontouchstart='openhelp();return false;' src='img/button_settings_inactive.png'></img></div>


         <div id='janelaConfig' style="display:block; opacity:0.0; height:5px; position:absolute; width:50px; left:100px; top: 175px; background-color:white; padding:20px;">

             <div id="wrapper2">
                 <div id="scroller2">
                     <p>Escolha sua regiao </p>
                     <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
                         <label for="txtRegiao"></label>
                         <select name="estado" id="estado" onchange="setCidade(this.SelectedIndex)">
                             <option name="BR" value="BR">Barueri</option>
                             <option name="BH" value="BH">Belo Horizonte</option>
                             <option name="BS" value="BS">Brasilia</option>
                             <option name="CP" value="CP">Campinas</option>
                             <option name="CU" value="CU">Cuiaba</option>
                             <option name="CT" value="CT">Curitiba</option>
                             <option name="DI" value="DI">Diadema</option>
                             <option  value="DQ">Duque de Caxias</option>
                             <option value="FL">Florianopolis</option>
                             <option value="FO">Fortaleza</option>
                             <option value="GO">Goiania</option>
                             <option value="GU">Guarulhos</option>
                             <option value="PA">Porto Alegre</option>
                             <option value="OS">Osasco</option>
                             <option value="RE">Recife</option>
                             <option value="RJ">Rio de Janeiro</option>
                             <option value="SS">Salvador</option>
                             <option value="SA">Santo Andre</option>
                             <option value="SB">São Bernardo do Campo</option>
                             <option value="SC">São Caetano do Sul</option>
                             <option value="SP">São Paulo</option>
                             <option value="VI">Vitória</option>
                         </select>
                         <p>Audio</p>
                         <select name="audio" id="audio" onchange="setAudio(this.SelectedIndex)">
                             <option value="on">Ligado</option>
                             <option value="off">Desligado</option>
                             <select><br><br><br>
                                 </form>
                     <p>&nbsp;</p>
                 </div>
                 <p>&nbsp;</p>
                 </div>
             </div>
                <div id="close"><img id='fechar' ontouchstart='closehelp();return false;' style='display:none; position:absolute; top:10px; right:3px;'  src='img/btn-fechar.png' /></div>
```

jQuery:

```
function closehelp() {

    $("#janelaConfig").animate({
        width: "50px",
        height: "5px",
        top: "175px",
        left: "100px",
        opacity: 0.0

    }, 250);
    $("#lblStatus").text("");
    $("#fechar").hide();

    $("#divinfo").show();
};

function openhelp() {

    $("#janelaConfig").animate({
        width: "82%",
        height: "70%",
        top: "20px",
        left: "8px",
        opacity: 0.9

    }, 250, function () {
        $("#fechar").show();

    });

};
```

Comment: Opacity will only work in firefox.

Comment: but work in mobile app. And work when I set to 1.0, but doesnt work when I reset to 0

Comment: I have too tried function closehelp()
{
    
    $("#janelaConfig").animate({
                               width: "50px",
                               height: "5px",
                               top : "175px",
                               left : "100px",
                               opacity: 0.0
                               
                               },250);
$("#lblStatus").text("");
$("#fechar").hide();
$("#janelaConfig").hide();

  $("#divinfo").show();
};

Comment: Can we see this live somehow?

Comment: When I use .hide, the div hide and appear again

Comment: I have created another div and put janelaConfig inside ..It works great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created another div and put janelaConfig inside ..It works great

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatly, the best way to handle opacity is through a couple of CSS tags:

```
.myElement {
    filter:alpha(opacity=50);
    -moz-opacity:0.5;
    -khtml-opacity:0.5;
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

However, once your opacity reaches 0, you're probably better off just hiding the element with

```
display:none;
```

Comment: Good catch, `display` is a better way to handle it.

Comment: `function closehelp(){$("#janelaConfig").animate({   width: "50px",     height: "5px",   top : "175px",   left : "100px", opacity: 0.0,display:"none" },250);
$("#lblStatus").text("");
$("#fechar").hide();
$("#divinfo").show();
};`?

Answer (score 0):

`opacity` will just change the `opacity` of the element `width`, `height` and `display` are not affected. Actually, the element will still be there, it'll just be invisible.

Comment: And I what I want is that the div be invisible

Comment: I mean, the elements will still be there and will be clickable/selectable.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment on another answer:

```
function closehelp() {
    $("#janelaConfig").animate({ width: "50px", height: "5px", top : "175px", left : "100px", opacity: 0.0,display:"none" },250);
    $("#lblStatus").text("");
    $("#fechar").hide();
    $("#divinfo").show();
};
```

Change your function to:

```
function closeHelp() {
    $('#janelaConfig').animate({
        height: 5,
        top: 175,
        left: 100,
        opacity: 0
    }, 250, function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
    $("#lblStatus").text("");
    $("#fechar").hide();
    $("#divinfo").show();
})
```

This will set your element's `display` to `none` *after* the animation has completed.

Comment: Change `$(this).hide()` to `$(this).css('display', 'none');` - does it work with this? If not, could you please show an example as I'm not sure why this wouldn't work otherwise!

Comment: Now it works better...the div flash...(disappear and appear again) but It is referenced only where I have posted in my answer...I have no ideia why the div appear again :S